# Is there a way to bind x:Arguments of a control in XAML?

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried to just bind the value between the Int32 brackets, but this code does not actually works, wondering if Xaml provides a way to do that.

```
<ListView x:Name="corsiList" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">
         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <ViewCell>
                       <ctrls:InfoCorso Title="{Binding CorsiList.Nome}" Time="18:30" StyleColor="{Binding ButtonColor}">
                            <x:Arguments>
                                 <x:Int32>Binding Subs</x:Int32>
                                 <x:Int32>Binding Max</x:Int32>
                            </x:Arguments>
                       </ctrls:InfoCorso>
                   </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, at present, we do not have support for binding the Arguments in Xamarin.

Refer to the below documentation for passing arguments in XAML.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/passing-arguments

Comment: @x_vale_x, If my reply helps you, please remember to mark my reply as an answer. Thanks...

Comment: Is it still impossible, even in MAUI?

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind to the arguments directly.

The best way to handle this is to add some bindable properties to your InfoCorso user control then update the arguments in code behind.

It looks like you already have a bindable property for Title, but if you need more information check this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties

Comment: I can’t because i have to perform calculus operation in the initialize component