# XAML binding as Arguments

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, maui

I'm trying to pass a view model as an argument of a page from XAML.

Here is the base page:

```
public abstract class BaseContentPage<T> : ContentPage where T : BaseVm
{
    public BaseContentPage(T viewModel, string pageTitle)
    {
        BindingContext = ViewModel = viewModel;
        Title = pageTitle;
    }

    protected T ViewModel { get; }
}

public abstract class BaseTabbedPage<T> : TabbedPage where T : BaseVm
{
    public BaseTabbedPage(T viewModel, string pageTitle)
    {
        BindingContext = ViewModel = viewModel;
        Title = pageTitle;
    }

    protected T ViewModel { get; }
}
```

A setting contains a list of devices defined this way:

```
public partial class SettingsPage : BaseTabbedPage<SettingsVm>
{
    public SettingsPage(SettingsVm vm) : base(vm, "Settings")
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class SettingsVm : BaseVm
{
    public DeviceListVm Devices { get; set; }

    public SettingsVm(ILogger<SettingsVm> logger, MyConfig config) { }
}

public partial class DeviceListPage : BaseContentPage<DeviceListVm>
{
    public DeviceListPage(DeviceListVm vm) : base(vm, "Devices")
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public DeviceListPage() : base(null, "Devices")
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then the hard stuff is in XAML:

```xml
<p:BaseTabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyProject.Pages"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
    xmlns:vmd="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels.Devices"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
    x:Class="MyProject.Pages.SettingsPage"
    x:TypeArguments="vm:SettingsVm">
    <NavigationPage Title="Schedule" IconImageSource="schedule.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <p:DeviceListPage ViewModel="{Binding Devices}">
                <!--x:Arguments>
                    <vmd:DeviceListVm>{Binding Devices}</vmd:DeviceListVm>
                </x:Arguments-->
            </p:DeviceListPage>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

</p:BaseTabbedPage>
```

I don't manage to pass Devices as an argument of DeviceListPage.

I don't want to do it programatically since model views are meant to be injected, except in this case where the root view model hold a sub view model to be use by a child page.

If I use ViewModel property, I get the following error:

> Error XFC0009:    No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "ViewModel", or mismatching type between value and property.

**EDIT**
I changed the base class to declare a `BindableProperty`:

```
public abstract class BaseContentPage<T> : ContentPage where T : BaseVm
{
    public BaseContentPage(T viewModel, string pageTitle)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
        Title = pageTitle;
    }

    public T ViewModel
    {
        get => (T)GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, BindingContext = value);
    }
    public BindableProperty ViewModelProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ViewModel), typeof(T), typeof(BaseContentPage<T>));
}

public abstract class BaseTabbedPage<T> : TabbedPage where T : BaseVm
{
    public BaseTabbedPage(T viewModel, string pageTitle)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
        Title = pageTitle;
    }

    public T ViewModel
    {
        get => (T)GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, BindingContext = value);
    }
    public BindableProperty ViewModelProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ViewModel), typeof(T), typeof(BaseTabbedPage<T>));
}
```

Then I still get the same XFC0009 error.

Comment: What type is DeviceListPage? You seem to have a `Protected T Viewmodel` but if you want to use it as you do, you should make a `BindableProperty`

Comment: @JuanSturla Binding a property applies a value to a default instance. Is it possible to pass the binding as a constructor argument?

Comment: Is [Passing Arguments  in XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/passing-arguments) what you're talking about?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT `<p:DeviceListPage>` is calling the default constructor `DeviceListPage()`. I'd like it to call the constructor with the view model `DeviceListPage(DeviceListVm vm)`

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Idon't find the syntax to use with a binding

Comment: As told by @Harikrishnan in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126162/is-there-a-way-to-bind-xarguments-of-a-control-in-xaml, it's not possible to pass a binding as an argument. I wonder if it's still true...